# how to remove inserted link using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Below is the sample code

here when i click the link, 'div' is added to the main box
but when i click div(.sub_box) its not remove

How i can activate 'div' click after adding

```
<div class="main_box">
<a href="#" class="add">add box</a>
<div class="sub_box">remove box</div>
</div>


$('.main_box .add').click(function () {
    $('.main_box').append('<div class="sub_box">remove box</div>');
});

$('.main_box div').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here since your div has been appended to the DOM dynamically:

```
$('.main_box').on('click','.main_box div',function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You added the sub_box class dynamically so use ***event delegation*** in jquery

```
$('.main_box').on('click' '.add', function () {
   $(this).append('<div class="sub_box">remove box</div>');
});

$('.main_box').on('click','.main_box div',function () {
            $(this).remove();
});
```